# Net volume reference for uptick and downtick

Tags: data, price, volume

I am new to finance and I have been looking at market data in terms of prices, volumes and net volumes. From what I have gathered:

Volume - number of transactions (buying-selling) throughout the specified time.

Net Volume - difference between the uptick and downtick during that time, which essentially, in the example shown in [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netvolume.asp#:~:text=Net%20volume%20is%20a%20technical,is%20leaning%20bullish%20or%20bearish.) means the difference between "downward" trades and "upward"  trades.

So, given an example where in the same hour I have 900 volumes, and +500 net volume, this means that 200 volumes were downward trades and 700 were upward trades. My questions is, upward/downward relative to what? to the initially buying price or to the most recent transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical **Net Volume** indicator operates on OHLCV bars, not on raw trades.

- Uptick is registered when the bar's close is higher than open
- Downtick is registered when the bar's close is lower than open
- Signed (directional) volume is positive on uptick, negative on downtick
- Net Volume is the cumulative sum of signed volumes

Let me illustrate the concept with an example using 5-minute bars.

```
| datetime |  open() | close() | tick | volume() | sign_volume | net_volume |
|----------|--------:|--------:|-----:|---------:|------------:|-----------:|
| 09:30:00 |   62.35 |   62.48 |    1 |    95611 |       95611 |      95611 |
| 09:35:00 |   62.42 |   62.97 |    1 |    50887 |       50887 |     146498 |
| 09:40:00 |   62.94 |   62.82 |   -1 |    45114 |      -45114 |     101384 |
| 09:45:00 |   62.90 |   62.30 |   -1 |    24267 |      -24267 |      77117 |
| 09:50:00 |   62.29 |   61.45 |   -1 |    72576 |      -72576 |       4541 |
| 09:55:00 |   61.45 |   61.43 |   -1 |    28622 |      -28622 |     -24081 |
| 10:00:00 |   61.48 |   61.98 |    1 |    28092 |       28092 |       4011 |
| 10:05:00 |   62.00 |   62.02 |    1 |    42849 |       42849 |      46860 |
```

The SQL query below fetches raw trades, calculates OHLCV bars, classifies the bars by price direction (`tick` column), and finally sums up signed volumes.

```
SELECT *, SUM(signed_volume) AS net_volume FROM (
SELECT symbol, datetime, open(), close(), 
  CASE 
    WHEN close()>open() THEN 1
    WHEN close()<open() THEN -1
    ELSE 0
  END AS tick,
  volume(), 
  tick*volume() AS signed_volume
FROM atsd_trade WHERE symbol = 'NTAP.US'
AND datetime BETWEEN '2021-02-26' AND '2021-02-27'
GROUP BY exchange, class, symbol, PERIOD(5 minute)
    ) WITH ROW_NUMBER(symbol ORDER BY datetime) > 0
```

Net Volume over OHLCV bars is sensitive to the bar period.

[image]

You can perhaps stabilize it by using vwap and/or by tightening the tick condition so that it takes a larger price move to cause a change in net volume.

```
    WHEN vwap()>prev_vwap THEN 1
    WHEN vwap()<prev_vwap THEN -1
    ELSE 0
```

```
    WHEN close()>open()*1.001 THEN 1
    WHEN close()<open()*0.999 THEN -1
    ELSE 0
```

**Trade direction** (buy or sell) is not part of **Net Volume** calculation. Also, it's not the same as the order direction. In limit order books, a transaction is classified as BUY when an incoming buy order is instantly matched with a standing sell order. If the incoming buy order is not matched, it is placed in the order book, and the trade will be classified as SELL when a later sell order takes it. In other words, as @user47399 mentioned, the trade direction == liquidity taker's order direction. During auctions, when the limit order book is not used, trade direction is based on order numbers as assigned by the exchange. Of the two participating auction orders, the trade direction is inferred from the later order. To correctly determine trade direction one needs access to full order log or to a trade feed where records are pre-classified by the exchange.

Buy trades can be downtick trades and sell trades can be uptick trades. In the example below BUY trade 3657601171 is a downtick, whereas SELL trade 3657602494 caused an uptick.

```
| datetime                   |  price | quantity | side | prev_price | tick |  trade_num |
|----------------------------|-------:|---------:|------|-----------:|-----:|-----------:|
| 2021-02-26 11:01:43.482121 | 35.251 |        1 | B    |            |    0 | 3657600807 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:47.289811 | 35.243 |       90 | B    |     35.251 |   -1 | 3657601171 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:47.289811 | 35.243 |       10 | B    |     35.243 |    0 | 3657601172 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:51.535774 | 35.242 |       11 | B    |     35.243 |   -1 | 3657601628 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:59.153104 | 35.270 |        1 | S    |     35.242 |    1 | 3657602494 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:59.153104 | 35.260 |        1 | S    |     35.270 |   -1 | 3657602495 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:59.153104 | 35.252 |       11 | S    |     35.260 |   -1 | 3657602496 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:59.682744 | 35.252 |       79 | S    |     35.252 |    0 | 3657602528 |
| 2021-02-26 11:01:59.682744 | 35.252 |       21 | S    |     35.252 |    0 | 3657602529 |
```

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT datetime, price, quantity, side, LAG(price) AS prev_price, 
  CASE 
    WHEN price>prev_price THEN 1
    WHEN price<prev_price THEN -1
    ELSE 0
  END AS tick, trade_num
FROM atsd_trade WHERE symbol = '-- redacted
AND datetime BETWEEN '2021-02-26 11:01:40' AND '2021-02-26 11:02:00'
) --WHERE (side = 'B' AND tick = -1 OR side = 'S' AND tick = 1)
```

For meaningful results, Net Volume calculated over raw trades would need to group quantities by the exact trade time (and order number) so that simultaneous trades triggered by the same order are treated as one transaction.

For instance, how would you classify SELL trades 3657602494, 3657602495, 3657602496, all originated by the same SELL order and registered at the same time? I think it should be treated as an uptick of 13 lots.

Answer (score 0):

Net volume is not relative to anything. It is just a tally (summation) of the *quantity* of executed buy orders (+1 per share bought) and executed sell orders (-1 per share sold). Net volume is *not* the *value of transactions*, that would be price multiplied by quantity.

Comment: How can net volume exist if for every sell there must be a buy? Shouldn't it always equal?

Comment: You need a Trade Classification Algorithm to classify each trade as a Buy or Sell. There are many algorithms available. For example a trade at the bid can be classified as a Sale and a trade at the ask, a Buy.

Comment: @user47399 it is an classif algo that decides if it is a Buy or Sell initiated order. For each trade, there is a liquidity provider (being publicly visible before the trade) and a liquidity consumer (who cross the bid-ask spread). The later one is the initiator of the trade: if he buys, it is a Buy order; if he sells, it is a Sell order. See https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/10739